# Notify Google of sitemap change when any content on website changes

Tags: php, seo, xml-sitemap

I've used Wordpress's plugin that notifies a few search engines every time you make a new post. However i'm thinking of developing a website that users submit stuff to, how can i use PHP to notify Google with an XML sitemap (or similar method) of the site changes as and when they happen, so users submissions are searchable/indexed quickly by Google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To ping Google, the ping url is:

> http://www.google.com/webmasters/sitemaps/ping?sitemap=http://www.yoursite.com/sitemap-file.xml

Answer (score 0):

For `PHP`:

```
file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/webmasters/sitemaps/ping?sitemap=https://domain.tld/sitemap.xml")
```

For `Python`:

```
import requests
requests.get("https://www.google.com/webmasters/sitemaps/ping?sitemap=https://domain.tld/sitemap.xml")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
shell_exec('ping -c1 www.google.com/webmasters/sitemaps/ping?sitemap=http://www.website.com/sitemap.php');
```

Answer (score -1):

Issue your request to the following URL: `www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap=sitemap_url`
Issue the HTTP request using wget, curl, or another mechanism of your choosing.
A successful request will return an HTTP 200 response code, if you receive a different response, you should resubmit your request.